# Sublime Text 2 Package Control error

Tags: proxy, sublimetext2

```
CTRL SHIFT P -> Package control : Install package
```

If I go here, I get an error straight away

```
'Package Control: There are no packages available for installation'
```

I suspect this might be because of my college authenticated proxy. But I've already set my system variables regarding this correctly, so stuff like URLLIB2 work well.

I also added (with the correct values)

```
"http_proxy": "http://id:pass@proxy:port",
"https_proxy": "http://id:pass@proxy:port",
```

to Package control's default settings. Still I'm getting this error. Any idea how to debug this further?

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by adding `"http_proxy": "your.proxy:port", "https_proxy": "your.proxy:port"` to the end of my `User/Package Control.sublime-settings` config file.

Comment: Thought I'd add that its located at Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – Default

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my settings, you have to set your proxy in the general Settings - User file for Sublime Text, not the general settings in the Package Control.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the syntax you used for setting the proxy?

Comment: Same as in the question: 
`"http_proxy": "aproxy.com:port"`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Adding to Package Control settings did work.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by following steps:

1. open your Internet Explorer
2. tools →internet options→ advanced tag→ Security → Cancel "Check for Server Certificate revocation"
   this checkbox
3. Restart your Sublime Text and it work!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure curl is installed as the package controller needs it.

```
apt-get install curl
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your credentials using separate parameters `proxy_username` and `proxy_password` in your User Settings. **Do not** use http:// or any other prefixes in proxy URL, since http_proxy and https_proxy should contain only proxy server domain (or IP) and port, separated by a colon.

I've experienced same trouble on my work machine because of NTLM proxy, and following settings works for me:

```
"http_proxy": "my-company-proxy:3128",
"https_proxy": "my-company-proxy:3128",
"proxy_username": "my-company-domain\\mamontov_se", // domain\login
"proxy_password": "MyPa$$w0rD",
```

Comment: Re: your deleted question, have a look at Guava's `RateLimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the four settings("http_proxy", "https_proxy", "proxy_username", "proxy_password") others mentioned before, there's also a "**user_agent**" setting that might matter.

Since the default value ("Sublime Package Control v%s") of "user_agent" isn't a browser, packets containing it might be refused by the proxy. In this case "faking" it in "Preference->Package Settings->Package Control->Settings -- User" might help:

```
"user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

PS. Wireshark is a good tool of checking what's the actual reason that downloading failed.

Answer (score 0):

Use follow code to install Package controll. Replace your proxy protocol, username , password , url and port config:

```
import urllib2,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": "<proxy protocol><user>:<password>@<proxy url>:<proxy port>"})) ); by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
```