# Sublime3 throw error after added the proxy details

Tags: proxy, sublimetext3

In my `sublime3` (standalone) I am getting the error, while i run a command:

```
`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
`
```

I understand that, it require the proxy setting and credentials, for that I ran this command adding my proxy informatins:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http":"**http://xxxx:xxxxxx@172.18.18.87:80/**"})) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

after I done that, I updated my user setting like this:

```
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "AdvancedNewFile",
        "Alignment",
        "AngularInject",
        "AngularJS",
        "Bootstrap 3 Jade Snippets",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "EasyDiff",
        "Emmet",
        "FileDiffs",
        "HTML5",
        "HTMLBeautify",
        "Jade",
        "Jade Build",
        "Jade Snippets",
        "jQuery",
        "Open-Include",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint",
        "Theme - Afterglow",
        "Theme - Soda",
        "WhoCalled Function Finder"
    ],
    "http_proxy": "http://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@172.18.18.87:80/", 
    "https_proxy": "http://xxxxxx:xxxxx@172.18.18.87:80/"
}
```

After restarting `sublime3` - still i am getting same error. how to fix this?

any one help me to sort out this please?

Answer (score 0):

You should use dedicated variables for the proxy username and password (`proxy_username` and `proxy_password`) and `http_proxy`/`https_proxy` should be in the form `domainname:port` or `ip:port`.

In example:

```
"http_proxy": "proxyserver:8080",
"https_proxy": "proxyserver:8080", // If http_proxy is set and this settings is not, the value from http_proxy will be used.
"proxy_username": "username",
"proxy_password": "password"
```

Also double check your proxy port, as `80` is not a common port for a proxy. And make sure that you've curl installed (e.g. `apt-get install curl`) as the package controller needs it.
Eventually check if your `~/.curlrc` file doesn't override any settings.

If nothing helps, then set `debug` to `true`, so it'll print HTTP headers and other debug information to the Sublime Text console, so you can investigate the issue further.

Please also check:

- [Package Control Docs Settings](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/settings#setting-http_proxy)
- [Sublime Text 2 Package Control error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521167/sublime-text-2-package-control-error)